# DBT + SNOWFLAKE INTERNAL STORAGE - File format 'GA4_GCS_PARQUET_FM' does not exist or not authorized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have an internal stage in Snowflake with parquet files that I want to apply a select.

I use the following piece of code:

```
WITH GA4_RAW_DATA AS (
    SELECT
        $1::VARIANT AS RAW_DATA,
        METADATA$FILE_LAST_MODIFIED AS LAST_MODIFIED,
        METADATA$filename AS STG_FILE_NAME
    FROM @{{schema}}.GA4_GCS_IS_PARQUET
    WHERE METADATA$FILENAME like '%events_%'

    {% if is_incremental() %}
        where LAST_MODIFIED not in (
            select LAST_MODIFIED from {{this}} )
    {% endif %}
)
```

With this I am able to access the parquet file.
However, I get this error:

```
15:26:38  Database Error in model raw_all_events (models\Raw\raw_all_events.sql)
15:26:38    002003 (02000): SQL compilation error:
15:26:38    File format 'GA4_GCS_PARQUET_FM' does not exist or not authorized.
15:26:38    compiled SQL at target\run\cdp_ga4\models\Raw\raw_all_events.sql
```

I checked the privileges of it.
I've noticed when running the following statement that I have two privileges for the same role (one is ownership and the other is usage):

```
SHOW GRANTS ON FILE FORMAT GA4_GCS_PARQUET_FM;
```

I searched the internet to check if this could impact the privilege of my role and I even changed the PROFILE.YML file to include things like:

```
privileges: all
```

or

```
privileges:
        - on: file format GA4_GCS_PARQUET_FM
          to: role CDP_GA4_DEV_CONTRIBUTOR_ROLE
          privileges: [SELECT, COPY, READ]
```

But I still get the same error.

Any sugestions?

Comment: Can you try the SELECT via Snowflake UI using the same role?

Answer (score 0):

So, after emailing dbt, I've had 3 people from them trying to help and no one understood what was happening.

However, I eventually found out the dumb solution -.-

I just added these lines at the beginning of the model:

```
  {% set use_schema %}
    use schema CDP_GA4_RAW;
  {% endset %}
  {% set query_result = run_query(use_schema) %}
```

We shouldn't need to specify the schema since we do that on the source.yml file:

```
    sources:
      - name: CDP_GA4_RAW
        database: |
           {%- if  target.name == "DEV" -%} CDP_GA4_DEV_DB
```

So there you have it.